# Problema al conseguir el valor de una variable en un objeto desde un proyecto diferente

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un proyecto que utilizo como librería en otro proyecto diferente.

En la librería, tengo un objeto con una variable. Me gustaría poder acceder al valor de esta variable en el otro proyecto donde se importa esta biblioteca, pero siempre obtengo NULL. Hay alguna forma de obtener el valor de esta variable en el otro proyecto?

Método 1:

```
fun method1() : MyModel{
   var stringOne = ""
   var stringTwo = ""

   //I do something with this two strings

   return MyModel(stringOne,stringTwo)
}
```

Método 2:

```
    fun method2(){
       Thread{
         while(true){
             PairListVariable.pairList = method1()
         }
       }.start()
    
    }




 object PairListVariable{
        var pairList = MyModel(null, null)
 }
```

En el método 1 lo que quiero hacer es obtener el valor de los dos `String` y almacenarlos en el modelo con el return: `return MyModel(stringOne,stringTwo)`. En el método dos, la idea es hacer un bucle del primer método y asignar en la variable del objeto PairListVariable llamada pairList, el valor que se retornó en el primer método, `PairListVariable.pairList = method1()` .

En el objeto defino la variable pairList y la inicializo pero cuando la llamo desde otro proyecto, siempre devuelve null y no devuelve el resultado de la ejecucion del metodo 1 tal y como digo en esta linea `PairListVariable.pairList = method1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente instancia la clase que contiene el método (suponiendo que la clase se llama `ClassA` :

```
var classA = ClassA()
```

y llamas el método que los almacenarías en una variable de tipo `MyModel`,

```
var model : MyModel = classA.method1()
```